# Passing id values from form and display result

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to pass value from form inputs to script and calculate. That is from `#no_of_rounds`, `#specific_round`, `#analysis_report_pages`, `#analysis_report_slides` to script using `document.getElementById().value`. One will select a value from no of rounds and multiply with specified rounds, i.e. 10. Then the outcome is added to given numbers from Analysis Report, Pages and Analysis Report, Slides.

```js
document.querySelector('.form').addEventListener('change', function() {
  const nr = +document.getElementById('no_of_rounds').value || 0;
  const sr = +document.getElementById('specific_round').value || 0;
  const arp = +document.getElementById('analysis_report_pages').value || 0;
  const ars = +document.getElementById('analysis_report_slides').value || 0;

  arp = 40;
  ars = 20;


  if (nr == 1) {
    const total = (90 * sr) + ar + ars;
  } else if (nr == 2) {
    const total = (90 * sr) + ar + ars;
  } else if (nr == 3) {
    const total = (100 * sr) + ar + ars;
  } else if (nr == 4) {
    const total = (110 * sr) + ar + ars;
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
});
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">


    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Number of Rounds</th>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="no_of_rounds" required="" id="no_of_rounds">

            <option style="background-color:skyblue;">Select no. of Rounds</option>
            <option value="1">1st Round</option>
            <option value="2">2nd Round</option>
            <option value="3">3rd Round</option>
            <option value="4">4th Round</option>
            <option value="5">5th Round</option>
            <option value="6">6th Round</option>
            <option value="7">7th Round</option>
            <option value="8">8th Round</option>
          </select>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Specific Rounds</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="specific_round" id="specific_round" placeholder="Specific Rounds" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Analysis Report, Pages</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="analysis_report_pages" id="analysis_report_pages" placeholder="Analysis Report, Pages" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Analysis Report, Slides</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="analysis_report_slides" id="analysis_report_slides" placeholder="Analysis Report, Slides" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Total</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total" id="total" class="bg-dark  text-white border-0">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Email Address -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Issue: No, any value is passed and calculated. Kindly help

Comment: form doesn't have `class="form"`

Comment: In other words: It's not that useful to apply a `'change'` event listener to a `<div />` tag

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, that yo defined the var total multiple times within the if else brakes.

The var lives only within thes brakes and can not be used after the brakes.

And you have to convert the values from string to number, before the `nr == 1`  can work :       `nr = parseInt(nr,10);`

Try this:

```js
document.querySelector('.form form').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var nr = +document.getElementById('no_of_rounds').value || 0;
  var sr = +document.getElementById('specific_round').value || 0;
  var ar = +document.getElementById('analysis_report_pages').value || 0;
  var ars = +document.getElementById('analysis_report_slides').value || 0;
  nr = parseInt(nr,10);
  ar = 40;
  ars = 20;
  
  sr = 20;

  var total=0;

  if (nr == 1) {
     total = (90 * sr) + ar + ars;
   
  } else if (nr == 2) {
     total = (90 * sr) + ar + ars;
  } else if (nr == 3) {
     total = (100 * sr) + ar + ars;
  } else if (nr == 4) {
     total = (110 * sr) + ar + ars;
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = total;
});
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">


    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Number of Rounds</th>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" name="no_of_rounds" required="" id="no_of_rounds">

            <option style="background-color:skyblue;">Select no. of Rounds</option>
            <option value="1">1st Round</option>
            <option value="2">2nd Round</option>
            <option value="3">3rd Round</option>
            <option value="4">4th Round</option>
            <option value="5">5th Round</option>
            <option value="6">6th Round</option>
            <option value="7">7th Round</option>
            <option value="8">8th Round</option>
          </select>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Specific Rounds</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="specific_round" id="specific_round" placeholder="Specific Rounds" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Analysis Report, Pages</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="analysis_report_pages" id="analysis_report_pages" placeholder="Analysis Report, Pages" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Analysis Report, Slides</th>
        <td><input type="number" name="analysis_report_slides" id="analysis_report_slides" placeholder="Analysis Report, Slides" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th class="text-muted h5">Total</th>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total" id="total" class="bg-dark  text-white border-0">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Email Address -->
  </form>
</div>
```